# SemanticImport fails with all files on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: bugs, import

MacOS 10.13
Mathematica 11.2.0.0
This is part of an assignment - my Semanticimport fails with all files though.
the error:
 `Dataset ExtractRawData::dataextr: Data extraction failed.`

The code is in the screenshot attached - all semanticImports fail, not only this specific csv.

[image]

If I do a simpler import like:

```
dataSemantic = Import[("/Users/dave/Dropbox/Uni/appliedempirical/DATA A0 2.csv")];
dataA0 = Dataset@dataSemantic;
```

it all works out. Can somebody help me with this?

**EDIT:**
I have now tried to use semanticImportString and drag and dropped the file. it seems to import it, but after querying I still get an error:

```
SemanticImportString[Missing["PartInvalid", "age"],
```

Missing["KeyAbsent", "age"]]

Comment: Try `Import[file, "Dataset"]`. Are you able to upload your files?

Comment: I have issues to with `SemanticImport` on Mac OS 10.13. Even examples from the Documentation simply return `$Failed`. I added the Bugs tag

Comment: Same here, SemanticImport fails with every try.

Comment: Having the exact same issue Mac OS 10.13.1 all examples of SemanticImportString from the Documentation return $Failed

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug specific to macOS 10.13 ("High Sierra").

It is caused by incompatibility between the operating system and the `golang` runtime library used by the binary component of `SemanticImport` (and of course `SemanticImportString`).

A fix for this issue has been released via paclet update. The update should be installed automatically when `SemanticImport` is first used in a fresh session, and the following code may be run to obtain the update manually

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
PacletUpdate["SemanticImport"]
```

after which the paclet version should be 0.0.457.